# Multiple parameter binding in laravel DB:Raw FOR WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, sql-server

Can anyone how to do that multiple parameter binding??

```
$userTypeID = [1,2,3];
$userDeptID = [1,4,6];
$arr = join(",",$arr);
DB::select("select * from users WHERE userTypeID IN (?,?,?) AND userDeptID IN(?,?,?)");
```

I was stuck in this problem for so long.
Thanks For Help!

Comment: I'm not able to use it because I have a complex query for which I'm DB: raw. So to prevent it from SQL Injection I've to bind the parameters. Please guide me for DB: raw in the question I just provided you the example code but the actually was so complex.

Comment: I'm not able to use eloquent because I have a complex query for which I'm using DB: raw. So to prevent it from SQL Injection I've to bind the parameters. Please guide me for DB: raw in the question I just provided you the example code but the actually was so complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent using

```
...WhereIn(...arr)
```

e.g

```
function scopeSomething($q, $array)
{
     return $q->where(function($q) use ($array) {
        foreach($array as $k => $v){
            $q->whereIn($k, $v);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to use it because I have a complex query for which I'm DB: raw. So to prevent it from SQL Injection I've to bind the parameters.
Please guide me for DB: raw in the question I just provided you the example code but the actually was so complex.